# Angular - Dropdown validation - Validation is shown before the mouseup event

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, angular-reactive-forms, primeng-dropdowns

I'm using reactive forms for implementing validation behavior.
I have a problem with the validation of a dropdown component. The validation is shown before the mouseup event (The problem (yt link): [Dropdown Validation](https://youtu.be/I6PYd8rp0Qo))

Stackblitz link: https://angular-um4dtz.stackblitz.io/

**.html**

```
<div class="col-md-8">
                <p-dropdown id="regionId" [required]="true" formControlName="selectedRegion"
                    placeholder="Select region (required)" [options]="regions" optionLabel="name"
                    [ngClass]="{'ng-invalid ng-dirty is-invalid' : (equipmentForm.get('selectedRegion').touched || equipmentForm.get('selectedRegion').dirty) && !equipmentForm.get('selectedRegion').valid }">
                </p-dropdown>
                <span class="invalid-feedback">
                    <span *ngIf="equipmentForm.get('selectedRegion').errors?.required">
                        Please select a region.
                    </span>
                </span>
</div>
```

My question is, Is this expected behavior or?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of a youtube link, e.g., on [stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com).

Comment: @Batajus stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-um4dtz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as far as I understood from debugging, it is weirdly the expected behavior.

Your input control `selectedStock` has directly folowing error state: `{ "required": true }`. Due to that, your error message

```
<span class="invalid-feedback">
  <span *ngIf="equipmentForm.get('selectedStock').errors?.required">
    Please select a stock.
  </span>
</span>
```

is already existing in the HTML. **But** it is not shown because of the CSS class `invalid-feedback`. It becomes visible as soon as you want to click on your dropdown option because the input control becomes dirty and the class `is-invalid` is applied.

And as far as I know, you don't need to set the class `ng-invalid` by yourself to the control because it will be set by Angular.

**Solution**

The only way I found, at the moment, is following:

```
<p-dropdown
  ...
  (onHide)="equipmentForm.get('selectedStock').markAsDirty()"
  [ngClass]="{
    'is-invalid': equipmentForm.get('selectedStock').dirty && !equipmentForm.get('selectedStock').valid
  }">
</p-dropdown>
```

In this approach you mark the control as dirty as soon as the dropdown overlay gets closed. So, your error is shown afterward.

Comment: How can I solve this problem. Do you have any solution? I want to show a validation error after the left mouse click is released, not when it is clicked. The current situation is extremely user-unfriendly.

Comment: I've added a solution. I hope it helps but I don't know if that's the best approach here

Comment: Okay, this can be a solution, I'll try to find out a better solution and if I don't, I'll mark this answer as correct. Thank you :)